# Angular 6, NGXS & Firestore

Tags: firebase, architecture, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, ngxs

I have a Firestore DB that has collections arranged similar to a relational DB in that related collections store foreign keys. This decision was made to make it easier for integration with existing .Net services as well as allowing for greater flexibility.

Here is part of the data model:

[image]

I have split my state into feature modules and have code such as this:

```
  ngxsOnInit(ctx: StateContext<SchedulesStateModel>) {
    ctx.dispatch([
      new GetScheduleGroups(),
      new GetSchedules()
    ]);
  }

  @Selector()
  static scheduleGroups(state: SchedulesStateModel): Array<ScheduleGroup> {
    return state.scheduleGroups;
  }

  @Selector()
  static scheduleGroupById(state: SchedulesStateModel) {
    return (scheduleGroupId: string) => {
      return state.scheduleGroups.filter((scheduleGroup: ScheduleGroup) =>
        scheduleGroup.id === scheduleGroupId);
    };
  }

  @Action(GetScheduleGroups)
  getScheduleGroups({ patchState }: StateContext<SchedulesStateModel>) {
    return this.dataService.getDocuments$<ScheduleGroup>('scheduleGroups')
      .pipe(tap(scheduleGroups => patchState({ scheduleGroups })));
  }

  @Action(GetSchedules)
  getSchedules({ patchState }: StateContext<SchedulesStateModel>) {
    return this.dataService.getDocuments$<Schedule>('schedules')
      .pipe(tap(schedules => patchState({ schedules })));
  }
```

In a ScheduleListComponent, I then have this code:

```
  getSchedulesById$(scheduleGroupId: string) {
    return this.store.select(SchedulesState.schedulesByGroupId)
      .pipe(map(schedulesFilter => schedulesFilter(scheduleGroupId)));
  }
```

I could move the retrieval logic of getSchedulesById$ into the state class, but the way I have the code structured at the moment, I need a way of retrieving Schedules for each ScheduleGroup; since ScheduleGroup is iterated over and the Schedules for each group are retrieved for display. This can be seen in the following template snippet:

```
<ngb-tab
  *ngFor="let scheduleGroup of (getScheduleGroups$(scheduleGroupCollection.id) | async)"
  [title]="scheduleGroup.name">
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    <div class="schedules-container" [ngStyle]="{ height: tabHeight }">
      <ibms-schedules-list-item
        *ngFor="let schedule of (getSchedules$(scheduleGroup.id) | async)"
        [schedule]="schedule">
      </ibms-schedules-list-item>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
```

This code works, but it seems verbose. Is there a better way of doing this?

One of the problems that I have is that even simple components end up becoming containers. Using the ScheduleListComponent as an example, it needs to display data from a related table. Fetching this data depends on which particular Schedule item is in focus during an *ngFor iteration.

Any suggestions for improvement? I'm almost certain there is a better method, but I'm not sure what it is.

Also, here is the data service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/internal-compatibility';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import WhereFilterOp = firebase.firestore.WhereFilterOp;

import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  getDocuments$<T>(collectionName: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.db.collection<T>(collectionName).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(action => {
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        const data: T = action.payload.doc.data() as T;
        data[ 'id' ] = id;
        return <T>data;
      }))
    );
  }

  getDocumentsByQuery$<T>(collectionName: string, propertyName: string,
                          comparisonOperator: WhereFilterOp, targetValue: string | boolean): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.db.collection<T>(
      collectionName,
      ref => ref.where(propertyName, comparisonOperator, targetValue)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(action => {
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        const data: T = action.payload.doc.data() as T;
        data[ 'id' ] = id;
        return data;
      }))
    );
  }

  addDocument<T>(collectionName: string, document: T) {
    const guid: string = Guid.raw();
    return fromPromise(this.db.collection<T>(collectionName).doc(guid).set(document))
      .pipe(
        map(() => {
          const returnDocument: T = document;
          document[ 'id' ] = guid;
          return returnDocument;
        })
      );
  }

  addBatch<T>(collectionName: string, documents: Array<T>) {
    const batch = this.db.firestore.batch();
    const collectionRef = this.db.collection<T>(collectionName);

    documents.forEach((document: T) => {
      const guid: string = Guid.raw();
      const docRef = collectionRef.doc(guid).ref;
      batch.set(docRef, document);
    });

    return fromPromise(batch.commit());
  }

  updateDocument<T>(collectionName: string, document: T, data: any) {
    return this.db.collection<T>(collectionName).doc(document['id']).update(data);
  }

  deleteDocument<T>(collectionName: string, document: T) {
    return this.db.collection<T>(collectionName).doc(document['id']).delete();
  }

}
```

I know that this service can be improved and I will get around to doing this, but I thought I would include it for completeness.

Any suggestions for improvement would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions that might be worth considering:

Since schedules are always used within a group, it might be easier/neater to have a `@Selector` that projects that structure.

It could still be a dynamic selector with an argument of the `scheduleGroupId`, but rather then returning just the groups it could return the groups with a child collection of its `schedules`. Then in the template you only have a single `Observable` that you subscribe to, and it returns the shape of data you want.  That projection might be more suited to the UI, whereas keeping a flat structure probably makes life easier if you are patching that state later via CRUD operations on the schedules?

> One of the problems that I have is that even simple components end up becoming containers. Using the ScheduleListComponent as an example, it needs to display data from a related table. Fetching this data depends on which particular Schedule item is in focus during an *ngFor iteration.

I'm not too clear on what you mean by this - since you are are dispatching the actions to `GetSchedules` and `GetScheduleGroups` via the NGXS initialisation hook you'll have everything eagerly fetched anyway right? I might be misunderstanding something here.

Is having component `SchedulesListItem` causing a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Garth. Your suggestion of providing a projected view of the data is nice. That would certainly help in keeping my usage of the state slices simpler. Containerizing components is happening more in other parts of my app. I have Booking state that has userId. When I iterate over BookingListItem, I have to pull the username from state; thereby making the otherwise simple component a container with store access.

Comment: No problem - if you need to access username from another state you might be able to create a [joining selector](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#joining-selectors) to help (just a guess without seeing your state structure).